Почему при изменении путей в файле NuGet.Config изменился только 1 путь из 4?
Необходимо изменить пути расположения Nuget пакетов, используя файл Nuget.config.
Код файла Nuget.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="D:\Nuget\Packages" />
    <add key="httpCache" value="D:\Nuget\HttpCache" />
    <add key="temp" value="D:\Nuget\Temp"/>
    <add key="pluginsCache" value="D:\Nuget\PluginsCache" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

После данного изменения с помощью команды  dotnet nuget locals all --list получаю следующий результат :
http-cache: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
global-packages: D:\Nuget\Packages
temp: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
plugins-cache: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache

но изменяется только один путь из четырех. В чем проблема? Помогите пожалуйста

Еще раз взгляните на ту документацию, что я вам дал, вы там видите настройки по типу httpCache, temp и pluginsCache? я вот нет... У global-packages  вижу там такое: "Переопределяет с помощью переменной среды NUGET_PACKAGES параметры конфигурации globalPackagesFolder или repositoryPath", то есть да, такая настройка есть, ну а вот к примеру у temp я вижу такое: "Переопределение с помощью переменной среды NUGET_SCRATCH.", то есть он переопределяется только переменной среды. Другими словами, вы придумали свои переменные, которых на самом деле не существует...

Теперь все получилось. Огромное спасибо вам )
